# Can I whitelist one ChromeCast device for multiple applications?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I have a ChromeCast device that I use for development. I have whitelisted the device and have received an AppId.

I am also developing an application for another company. Does the whitelisting support multiple AppIDs per device? Should I have them add my device to their whitelist request, or should I update the URLs associated with my AppID to the other company's receiver url(s)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share your device with them, you can request for more app-id/urls to be added to your device. Obviously, if you want them to use their own device, you need to get the serial number of their devices to whitelist theirs for your app or have them whitelist directly.å

Comment: So, this would be considered an "Other type of request" in the whitelist form ("What type of request is this?")? I assume that the contact owning the appId I request will be contacted.